# Correct way to rearrange x variable for multiple ggplot layer in `ggstatsplot` package

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the [documentation of `ggstatsplot` package](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/ggwithinstats.html),
I tried to rearrange the x variable in the custom order as `Wine B`, `Wine A` and `Wine C`, instead of default order.
**Problem** is that the ggline (another layer of ggplot) connecting the means, doesn't arranged in the given order.

```
library(WRS2)
ggstatsplot::ggwithinstats(
  data = WineTasting,
  x = Wine,
  y = Taste,
  type = "np", # non-parametric test
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  ggplot.component = list(scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Wine B", "Wine A", "Wine C")))
)
```

In the cropped output below, you can see that the red line connecting means, starts from `Wine A`, instead of the provided order.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder the factor in your dataset rather than reordering the ticks on the axis:

```
WineTasting$Wine <- relevel(WineTasting$Wine, 'Wine B')
ggwithinstats(
  data = WineTasting,
  x = Wine,
  y = Taste,
  type = "np", # non-parametric test
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE
)
```

[image: statsplot]
Note that this keeps the order of the colours in the graph unlike `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Thanks. Relevel only sets the first level. What if I want to create a custom order of all the levels?

Comment: For a generalized case (i.e. arranging all the levels) we can use,  `WineTasting$Wine <- factor(WineTasting$Wine, levels = c("Wine B", "Wine A", "Wine C"))`.

Comment: Exactly as kbc said. You'll have to use either `ordered` or `factor` and use the `levels` argument to set theorder.